# Adding content to a database table during module install

Tags: installation

I created a custom module and in the ".install" file, I create a table using hook_schema().

I have about 90 error codes that I have to associate with an error message.

What is the most effective way to populate my table with those values during module install?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As alternative of implementing `hook_install()`, if the module needs to be sure those data are present in the database before it runs, you can implement [hook_enable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7). The difference between those hooks is that `hook_install()` is executed once, when the module is installed; `hook_enable()` is executed all times the module is enabled, which happens also when the module is installed. Using `hook_enable()` requires you to first verify the data are not already present in the database before to write them.
Implementing `hook_enable()` is what the Forum module does to create the taxonomy vocabulary, and the taxonomy reference field it uses. (See [forum_enable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!forum!forum.install/function/forum_enable/7).)

Keep in mind that if you need to insert too much values in the database, then you should find another way to do it, as code taking too much time to be executed would cause a PHP timeout, and the code would not be complete the data insertion.
The alternative is using [batch operations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/batch/7), or [queue operations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7).

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert the values using [hook_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7)

From `hook_install()` API page:

> If the module implements [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7), the database tables will
>   be created before this hook is fired.

Code:

```
function MYMODULE_install() {
  // DB Insert code here.
}
```